# converting docx to pdf lowriter in azure pipeline but getting Error: source file could not be loaded

Tags: bash, azure-pipelines, converters

I am trying to convert a generated report(.docx)in my azure task to pdf but i get Error: source file could not be loaded. I am in the write directory and I can see the file exist in my directory. the lowriter command also works fine when i try it locally.can someone please help me?

```
      - task: Bash@3
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          workingDirectory: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
          script: |
            sudo apt install libreoffice-writer
            wget https://github.com/cnescatlab/sonar-cnes-report/releases/download/4.1.1/sonar-cnes-report-4.1.1.jar 
            java -jar sonar-cnes-report-4.1.1.jar -t mytoken -s mysqserver -p myproject --disable-spreadsheet --disable-markdown --disable-csv  -r ./code-analysis-template.docx 
            chmod 777 myfile.docx
            lowriter --headless --convert-to pdf myfile.docx
```

i tried the following command as well but it converts all of the other docx files except the report one.

```
lowriter --headless --convert-to pdf *.docx  --outdir mydirectory
```

Comment: 1. You are using `workingDirectory: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'`, please make sure the docx exists in the artifact.
2. list all files check if myfile.docx can be listed. command "ls -a". If it's in sub folder, fix the path.

Comment: yes the docx is in the artifact directory and i can see the file when i do ls -la

Comment: Download the specific file from artifact to local machine, are you able to convert it locally? If not, it should be issue on the file.

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT yes, am able to convert it locally

Comment: If there're some other docx files in the same directory, and they are able to be converted in the pipeline, it should be an issue on the specific file, please upload a new docx file to fix it. If you didn't check docx in same directory, please do it.

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT it's a docx report which is being generated automatically by using java -jar command